# Why do I report an error when I execute npm run build

Tags: npm, npm-build

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnHtN.png)

I want to execute npm run build to package into a dist folder, but when I execute this command, an error is reported. Is it related to the node version? I tried node versions 18.13.0 and 16.19.0, but it didn’t work.

Comment: Please update your question and add the `build` command script and your package.json file

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to add formatted code. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/20153035)